# UITextView setBorderStyle crashes in iOS 5 Simulator

Tags: objective-c, crash, ios-simulator, ios5

I have a strange situation in one view controller where this line crashes in the iOS 5 simulator:

```
   // myTextField is created in a NIB
   myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

It's okay in the device (and both device and simulator on iOS 4.3).  I've checked the connections in the NIB (even deleted and reconnected).  myTextField has a retainCount of 2 at this point in the code.  I'm setting other attributes (e.g., "text" and "userInteractionEnabled" prior to this point, and those do not cause a crash.

However, if I use this sequence, it does not crash:

```
   myTextField.borderStyle = 4; // not a defined border style
   myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

If I use 1, 2, or 3 (defined styles) instead of "4" (an undefined border style), it crashes.  "7" works.

In my other view controllers, I have similar textViews, and no problem setting the borderStyle to UITextBorderStyleNone.

Edit: Here's the backtrace:

```
Thread 1, Queue : (null)
#0  0x01e0609b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x005c1c22 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _setBackgroundColor:] ()
#2  0x005c3a06 in -[UIView(Rendering) setBackgroundColor:] ()
#3  0x0063eab7 in -[UITextField setBackgroundColor:] ()
#4  0x0063e1b6 in -[UITextField setBorderStyle:] ()
#5  0x000c23e6 in -[DutyEditViewController viewWillAppear:] at /Users/jeff/Applications/iPhone/MyApp/Classes/DutyEditViewController.m:197
#6  0x00651fbf in -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] ()
#7  0x0065221b in -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] ()
#8  0x006524c3 in -[UIViewController beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] ()
#9  0x00662b71 in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#10 0x006633df in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] ()
#11 0x00663986 in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] ()
#12 0x0c894dbd in -[UINavigationControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] ()
#13 0x006635a4 in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] ()
#14 0x000bf99a in -[DutiesTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] ()
#15 0x0061a71d in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] ()
#16 0x0061a952 in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] ()
#17 0x0025386d in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
#18 0x020dc966 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#19 0x020dc407 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#20 0x0203f7c0 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#21 0x0203edb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#22 0x0203eccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#23 0x0258a879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#24 0x0258a93e in GSEventRun ()
#25 0x0058aa9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#26 0x0006117d in main ()
#27 0x00002c65 in start ()
```

I notice that the setBorderStyle: is doing a setBackgroundColor:, so changed my code to this:

```
myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

and the crash no longer happens.  But, the background color is being set to "Clear Color" in the NIB.

So, the crash is gone, but the mystery of why I must set the background color (even though the NIB is already doing that) remains.

Comment: Thanks for the backtrace;  file a bug via bugreporter.apple.com and attach a binary of the crashing version of your app w/instructions on reproducing the crash, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.  It's an iOS 5.0 bug, and it's in iOS 5 on devices, too, not just the simulator.  A crash will occur when setting the UITextField borderStyle property if the backgroundColor has been set using UIColor's colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:.

There is no crash if the text field's backgroundColor has been set using a preset color, e.g., clearColor.  There is no crash if borderStyle is set to its current value.

I've submitted a but report to Apple (Bug ID 10381834).

Comment: I hit this bug when setting a UITextField background colour to 'white Color' via Interface Builder.  It doesn't help that when selecting 'white colour', the property is then shown as being 'Default color' but still crashes. Setting to 'Table Cell Grouped Background' fixed it for me, though I still need white.  @Jeff, thanks for posting your findings here, and reporting the bug.

Comment: ...and I found a workaround that gets the desired results: change the background color to groupTableViewBackgroundColor, set the borderStyle, and then change back to your desired colour. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `retainCount` is irrelevant;  meaningless, even.

Secondly, if you have a crash, then you have a backtrace and/or crash report.  Post it.

Finally, if it crashes in simulator but not on the device it might be a simulator bug.   Or not.  Could be a bug in your app that only fails catastrophically in the simulator.

Can't say more without more clues.

Comment: I have added a backtrace and discovered a way to prevent the crash, but it's still mysterious.  (I mentioned the retainCount because I didn't want someone to suggest that the UITextView was not retained.)